# Why my JUnit error collector is not reporting the error?

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to report error using JUnit error collector. Although my assertion is failing, error is not reported in JUnit. But I am getting the "error" message in console.

```
@Rule
public ErrorCollector errcol = new ErrorCollector();

@Then("^Business alert message on the screen$")
public void Business_alert_message_on_the_screen(Result_Update) throws Throwable {
    if (userType.equals("Admin")) {
        try {
            Assert.assertEquals("Update button is not present for the admin user", true, Result_Update);

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            errcol.addError(t);
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Which runner are you using (aka the class used as parameter for `@RunWith`)?

Comment: @RunWith(Cucumber.class)

Answer (score 1):

According to JUnit:

> The ErrorCollector rule allows execution of a test to continue after
> the first problem is found

```
 errcol.addError(t);//only adds the error to the ErrorCollector
```

This means that the test continues after collecting the error.

You should add:

```
 errcol.checkThat(...); //will pass/fail the test
```

See examples:

https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html (Updated)

https://gist.github.com/cb372/2419626

Comment: OK Thanks Lttiel. Will try this out.

Comment: What I can't get is why errcol.addError(t) only adds the error to the ErrorCollector and not fail the test. It's said that addError should also fail the test in the end. I refer to JUnit 4.12 JavaDoc.

Comment: @AlexanderItes errcol.addError() collects all errors of the test flows, failing/passing the test occurs in the errcol.checkThat() method.
Please share your code if you need further assistance.
Updated doc and example: 
https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html

Answer (score 1):

> **tl;dr** : Make sure your test class doesn't extend `TestCase`.

I had a similar problem when I was using JUnit 4 with IntelliJ IDEA.  I naïvely selected a base class of `TestCase` in the dialog, which was the default for JUnit 3, because I figured "it'd be nice to have those handy `this#assert*` methods" (the default for JUnit 4 is null).  The bad code (which didn't work) is below:

```
public class SassCompilerTest extends TestCase {
    @Rule
    public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();

    @Test
    public void testCompiler() throws IOException {
        collector.checkThat(true, CoreMatchers.equalTo(false));
    }
}
```

However, in JUnit 4, that prevented a lot of features from working.  Removing the parent class fixed the test:

```
public class SassCompilerTest {
    @Rule
    public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();

    @Test
    public void testCompiler() throws IOException {
        collector.checkThat(true, CoreMatchers.equalTo(false));
    }
}
```

The solution was suggested to me by a [comment](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/983#issuecomment-54520175) in the issue with Cucumber mentioned by @StefanBirkner in another answer.  After reading that, I tried extending `ErrorCollector` to make the `ErrorCollector#verify` public and call it from an `@After` method, but the `@After` method wasn't getting called, which made me realize something was either wrong with the TestRunner (which was IntelliJ's default) or the Test itself.

Comment: Is there any workaround in case of parent class usage? I have to keep my abstraction, but errorCollector does not work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `Cucumber` runner does not support `@Rule` because it extends `ParentRunner` and not `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner` (see [source code of the runner](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/junit/src/main/java/cucumber/api/junit/Cucumber.java)). There is already an [issue for supporting `ErrorCollector`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/771).

Comment: I got this. With cucumber (and parent class) I am unable to use errorCollector. Any workaround? Thanks!